# How do I fix pub get failed (66; Could not decompress gz stream Connection closed while receiving data, path = '')

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
#  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.2+1
#  firebase_auth: ^0.15.4
#  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+1
#  fluttertoast: ^3.1.3
#  image_picker: ^0.6.3+1
#  firebase_storage: ^3.1.1
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.0
#  provider: ^4.0.4
#  path_provider: ^0.5.0+1
  image: ^2.1.14
#  intl:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/welcome.png
    - images/login.png
    - images/admin.png
    - images/cash.png

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Signatra
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Signatra.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK3Ck.png)

How do I fix this error:

> pub get failed
> (66; Could not decompress gz stream Connection closed while receiving data, path = '')

I have tried using `flutter clean`, `flutter pub pub cache repair`
I have their results in pictures. Please help me, as I have never come across this bug before and there is no answer for it on Stack Overflow yet.

[Fault Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4emYq.png)

The error occurs when I try to pub get the following packages below:

flutter_staggered_grid_view:
image: ^2.1.14..

Comment: please post your error message in the question as code not as a screenshot , and also add the code that causes the error to appear

Comment: i have added a snippet now.. please help me out

Answer (score 8):

Clean flutter: `flutter clean`

Fix cache: `flutter pub cache repair`

Upgrade flutter `flutter upgrade`

If it doesn't work, run `flutter doctor` and show us the result.

Working pubspec.yaml

```yaml
description: A new Flutter application.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1
name: name_of_your_package

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.2
  image: ^2.1.14

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - images/welcome.png
    - images/login.png
    - images/admin.png
    - images/cash.png

  fonts:
    - family: Signatra
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Signatra.ttf
```

Comment: i have done that and i have updated my problem above ... please look at the pictures i shared

Comment: You have no version assigned to `flutter_staggered_grid_view`: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view/install

Comment: @HaroldKess, I've added fixed pubspec.yaml. Remember to change the `name` field to your own! And if something is still wrong, show the result of `flutter doctor --verbose`

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem has to do with your internet connection. Check if you're behind a proxy or a VPN. If yes, run the flutter pub get command without going through the proxy or VPN. Also, check your internet connection download speed.
Alternatively, you can add the package manually by following these steps:

1. Download the package archive. This is usually found on https://pub.dev/packages/PACKAGE_NAME/versions. Replace PACKAGE_NAME with the actual package name.
2. Unzip the file and place the extracted folder inside `home/username/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/` . This is where your downloaded packages are stored. For Windows, check `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org`
   For Mac, check `users/*username*/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/`
3. At the root folder of your project, run `flutter pub get` again. This time, it should be successful because there is nothing to download.

Answer (score 0):

try `flutter clean`
and then
`pub get`
good luck :)